# Drawing In Wpf Application too Slow

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I want to draw 1,000,000 lines in a Wpf Application.  However, when I draw to
MeshGeometry3D, the drawing is slow. How can the drawing speed be increased?

Answer (score 1):

These sites might help:

DrawingContext Class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx

WPF Graphics Overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx

Comment: Working with graphics at the visual layer will help performance (if you do it properly). For a million lines though (perhaps in a 3D mesh from your question), WPF may not be up to the job. Maybe you need to rethink your requirements or look into DirectX.